# ng-include tag and SVG images in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I've came across a strange issue. It's not like it's blocking something, but I thought that it would be better to understand this behavior. I use ng-include in AngularJS to include SVG images so I can style them with CSS.

So this code works fine:

```
<ng-include src="'resources/svg/mastercard.svg'"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="'resources/svg/paypal.svg'"></ng-include>
```

This works fine too:

```
<span><ng-include src="'resources/svg/mastercard.svg'" /></span>
<span><ng-include src="'resources/svg/paypal.svg'" /></span>
```

But this results in **Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null** error and only the first image shows up on the page:

```
<ng-include src="'resources/svg/mastercard.svg'" />
<ng-include src="'resources/svg/paypal.svg'" />
```

Basically, you can use multiple ng-include tags in one container if you close them with with a separate statement, but if you write it in a short manner - it must be one per container to work. Why is that? Is there something fundamental about it that I'm missing and should know?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Essentially you can't define your own void/self-closing tags in HTML. There are a limited number of these, as described at http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#void-elements :

> area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, menuitem, meta, param, source, track, wbr

Also, browsers effectively ignore the `/>`. So when you use an element that isn't in the list of void elements, such as `<ng-include ...`, such as in your example (wrapped in a `<div>`)

```
<div>
  <ng-include src="'resources/svg/mastercard.svg'" />
  <ng-include src="'resources/svg/paypal.svg'" />
</div>
```

the browser will parse it as

```
<div>
  <ng-include src="'resources/svg/mastercard.svg'">
    <ng-include src="'resources/svg/paypal.svg'"></ng-include>
  </ng-include>
</div>
```

and I suspect that causes the error you're seeing. The reason why the following works

```
<span><ng-include src="'resources/svg/mastercard.svg'" /></span>
<span><ng-include src="'resources/svg/paypal.svg'" /></span>
```

is that the browser recognises the closing `</span>` must close any tags opened since the opening `<span>`, and so parses it as:

```
<span><ng-include src="'resources/svg/mastercard.svg'"></ng-include></span>
<span><ng-include src="'resources/svg/paypal.svg'"></ng-include></span>
```